# How get a string from asset to double for latlng google maps v2 android

Tags: android, string, google-maps, double

i am new to android programming and i try to draw a polyline on google maps v2 android. the coordinates (more than 100) are stored in two txt-files (one txt for lat and one for lng) in asstes directory. i tryed to load the content of the files in a string but now i don't how to convert these to double for the polyline feature. 
Double.parseDouble(contentdlat); won't work!

the coordinates in the txt's ar seperatet with a "," and looks like:

dlat.txt = 42.4630,42.4539

dlng.txt = -75.0572,-73.9737

UPDATE: now i use only one file instead of two.

coord_short.txt = 42.4630,-75.0572,42.4539,-73.9737

the old code is shown below:

```
//Add Polyline
         ArrayList<LatLng> all=new ArrayList<LatLng>();
         ArrayList<Double> lat1=new ArrayList<Double>();
         ArrayList<Double> lon=new ArrayList<Double>();

         AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

         // To load dlat text file
         InputStream inputdlat;
         try {
         inputdlat = assetManager.open("dlat.txt");

         int sizedlat = inputdlat.available();
         byte[] bufferdlat = new byte[sizedlat];
         inputdlat.read(bufferdlat);
         inputdlat.close();

         // byte buffer into a string
         String contentdlat = new String(bufferdlat);
         Toast.makeText(this, contentdlat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         //String[] splitdlat = contentdlat.split(",");

         }
         catch (IOException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 }


        // To load dlng text file
         InputStream inputdlng;
         try {
         inputdlng = assetManager.open("dlng.txt");

         int sizedlng = inputdlng.available();
         byte[] bufferdlng = new byte[sizedlng];
         inputdlng.read(bufferdlng);
         inputdlng.close();

         // byte buffer into a string
         String contentdlng = new String(bufferdlng);
         Toast.makeText(this, contentdlng, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         //String[] splitdlng = contentdlng.split(",");

         }
         catch (IOException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 }

         double dlat = Double.parseDouble(contentdlat);
         double dlat = Double.parseDouble(contentdlng);

         //double[] dlat = {42.4630,42.4539};
         //double[] dlon = new double[]{-75.0572,-73.9737};

         for(double n : dlat){
         lat1.add(n);
         }

         for(double n : dlon){
         lon.add(n);
         }

         for(int a=0;a<lat1.size();a++)
         {
         LatLng allLatLng= new LatLng(lat1.get(a),lon.get(a));
         all.add(allLatLng);
         }

         Polyline polyline = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
         .addAll(all)
         .width(8)
         .color(Color.GREEN));
```

It will be great if anybody can help me.

Ok with Piyush Gupta's help i changed the code to:

```
         AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

         // To load coordinate text with hundreds of coordinates file like 
         InputStream input;
         try {

         input = assetManager.open("coord_short.txt");

         int size = input.available();
         byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
         input.read(buffer);
         input.close();

         // byte buffer into a string
         String content = new String(buffer);
         String[] separated = content.split(",");
         String latString = separated[0]; 
         String longString = separated[1];

         double coordlat = Double.parseDouble(latString);
         double coordlon = Double.parseDouble(longString);
         LatLng coordlocation = new LatLng(coordlat, coordlon);




             Polyline polyline = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
             .add(coordlocation)
             .width(8)
             .color(Color.GREEN));  



         }
         catch (IOException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 }
```

But now my Polyline is not drawn on the map.

whats now wrong?

Comment: Is there two different lat and longitude file in assets folder??

Comment: there is one file with the latitudes (dlat.txt) and one file with the longitudes (dlng.txt).

Comment: But generally in this dlat.txt = 42.4630,42.4539 file lat and longitude are available... so

Comment: these two coordinates are lat's and in the dlng.txt there are the needed lng's. this is what i want. but when i can do this in one file and split it with "," this will also be ok for me

Comment: You can save it to in only one text file also..

Comment: ok this means i use one txt file in asset with latlng coordinates like (42.4630,-75.0572,42.4539,-73.9737) and how i tell java that the 42.* is a lat and the -75.* is a lng? and by the way how i bring this to double/polyline?

Comment: After getting co-ordinates from .txt file in string, you can split that String....

Comment: so i split the string with this command "String[] splitcoord = contentcoord.split(",");" // I understand it so, with this command i have splitted the numbers by the "," . but now i don't know how i bring these numbers to the right lat lng position. how java knows that 42.* is lat and -75.* is lng to draw a polyline?

Comment: After split that string , the convert first string to Double as a Lat and convert second string also as a longitude... so you will get lat and longitude and from it you can draw a polygon ..

Comment: can you show me this with a code snippet?

Comment: there is no loop in 2nd code - you will read only 1 point

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("test.txt");
int size = is.available();
byte[] buffer = new byte[size]; //declare the size of the byte array with size of the file
is.read(buffer); //read file
is.close(); //close file

// Store text file data in the string variable
    String str_data = new String(buffer);
```

Comment: this snippet looks like the same to my code, where is the difference?